# Find the orthogonal projection using the given weighted inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

E.g. u = (2, 3) and v = (4, 1). The weighted Euclidian inner product can be given as 〈,〉 = 11 + 222.

Naturally
$$(u.v) = 1(2\times4) + 2(3\times1)$$

$$(u.v) = 8 + 6$$
$$(u.v) = 14$$

But what about the projection of u onto v?

Do we multiply everything by the weighted inner product?
Or just the (u.v) part and the (v)^2 part? (i.e. everything except the single v component)

I think it is the latter. i.e.
$$PROJvU = \frac{u.v}{v^2}v$$
$$PROJvU = \frac{14}{34}(4,1)$$
$$PROJvU = \frac{7}{17}(4,1)$$

(Alternative answer for multiplying everything would be $$\frac{7}{17}(4,2))$$

Please let me know if my instincts are correct.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Should I edit my original post?
Or post a new question with it written properly

Comment: What I meant was that you should edit your question.

Comment: Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if you're projecting something onto the vector $v$, you're going to get a solution in the form $\lambda v$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$. You want to find $\lambda$ such that 
$$
(v, u-\lambda v) = 0.
$$
We can rearrange this to $$
(v, u)=\lambda(v,v),
$$
i.e. 
$$
\lambda=\frac{(v, u)}{(v,v)}\\
PROJ_v(u)=\frac{(v, u)}{(v,v)}v.
$$
The same trick applies to finding the projection of $u$ onto the span of $v$ and $w$. Now we want to find $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that $(v,u- \lambda v - \mu w)=0$ and $(w,u-\lambda v - \mu w)=0$. Then just take $PROJ_{v,w}(u)=\lambda v+\mu w.$

That means we want to solve the system of equations
$$
\pmatrix{(v,u) \\ (w,u)}=\pmatrix{(v,v),&(v,w)\\(w,v),&(w,w)} \pmatrix{\lambda\\\mu}.$$
If the inner product can be represented with a symmetric, positive-definite matrix, say $M$, that turns into
$$\pmatrix{v^\top\\w^\top}Mu=\pmatrix{v^\top\\w^\top}M\pmatrix{v,&w}\pmatrix{\lambda\\\mu}.$$